# Problem with displaying admob ads inside vpn app

Tags: java, android, kotlin, admob

I'm having trouble showing admob ads inside my VPN app

When users from countries with low eCPM connect to VPNs from countries with higher eCPM, Google does not know the real country of the user and therefore limits the sending of ads.

For example, it shows ads that are in the UK to people in Japan and vice versa

There is no way that admob remembers the user's country during the initial implementation? or any other solution